# Multiple Polymer components in a single git endpoint

Tags: git, polymer, web-component

Both in [generator-polymer](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-polymer) and in Polymer core components there is a single git repository for each component. Is there a issue or limitation in having multiple component which are dependent and have similar external dependencies in the same git repository?

Answer (score 1):

We define **component** as an atomic shareable unit. So there will be one Git repository per component, but a component can contain any number of resources (e.g. multiple **custom elements**).

Comment: Hm, this answer isn't entirely clear to me. Would it correct to say that an endpoint is a resource that's identified by a canonical URL? Making `http://mysite.example.com/components/polymer/polymer.html` an endpoint and a component?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. In your example `polymer` is the component, `polymer.html` is a resource in that component. By `end-point` I was referring to a Git repository or other location from which one can acquire a component (and we call a component in a downloadable form a `package`).

Comment: Oh right, "git endpoint" is in the question title. Ignore me!